# Do super user still need to have execute permission for directory to enter it?

Tags: permissions, sudo, directory, root

I used my super user hoping that I will be able to do everything with it, but to access one directory, I still had to do `sudo su` command to switch to root because I was getting access denied. Then how come super user is super user and still can’t access directory? And if I was switching to root, why sudo su didn't ask for password for root user and it worked without or with super user password which wasn't allowed to execute dir?

Comment: My `pathlld` `bash` script will help you answer this question. See https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?"

Comment: root is superuser. Everybody else can merely become root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Superuser* and *root* [are synonyms](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo). Your user is probably a [sudoer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers), not a superuser.

In Ubuntu, you can perform a single command as root using the `sudo` command. Or you can open a root’s shell using `sudo su`, `sudo -s` or `sudo -i`. (I won’t discuss the differences here. Also, plain `su` could be used – if you knew the root’s password.)

`sudo cd` makes no sense since it would change the directory and then drop to *your* shell which might not be able to open the directory. Therefore Ubuntu disallows it completely:

```
$ sudo cd /root
sudo: cd: command not found
```

However, we can issue:

```
$ sudo ls -l /root
total 0
```

So how can we `cd` to the directory? We have to use a root shell:

```
$ sudo su
root@my-ubuntu:/home/mirek# cd /root
root@my-ubuntu:~# ls -l
total 0
```

You asked why you haven’t to input password in this case. It’s because you have used `sudo` recently. To force it to need the password again, you can issue `sudo -k`. Otherwise, it starts to require the password after a few minutes again.

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation. But then why do I need to use sudo in the first place if I already am super user? I mean I logged in with super user called “developer” which has SU privilegies.

Comment: @Limpuls you are not the super user. `developer` is not the super user. Only root is. `developer` can *become* the superuser, i.e., `root` using `su` (or `sudo`).

Comment: @Limpuls - see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: @Limpuls Adding to what muru said, your _developer_ user is a [sudoer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers), i.e. a user allowed to run `sudo`. Only _root_ should be called a _superuser_.

Comment: @Melebius Okay now I understand. So when we give privilegies to user and make him sudoer, he is allowed to use sudo command. Meaning that simple users by default can’t usd sudo command?

Comment: @Limpuls Exactly, users are not allowed to run `sudo` by default. See [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/404185/54675).

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the `cd` command with `sudo` or else you will get errors. You must run:

```
sudo su
```

or

```
sudo -s
```

to get into a root shell before using `cd` as root.